# <select> for <select> c# to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a ViewBag.List     > where i have competition, and every competition has a list of teams.
Example : List of {Premier League : [ Arsenal, Chelsea etc]
                   Bundesliga : [ Bayern Munchen, Wolfsburg etc]

I have 2 selects. When the user selects the first select ( competition ), i want that the second select will have the teams from the competition. If he selects Premier League, the second select will have Arsenal,Chelsea etc.

I tried to have a select for every competition, and if he selects one, that one will be visible and the other ones hidden or none, but all the selects are linked with asp-for  string CurrentTeam and i can't put the team in the database.

Another option was with a javascript function. 
Whenever the user selects a competition - > onclick = "myfunction (this)"
and in that function i have something like this:

```
    function myFunction(select) {
        var sel = document.getElementById("teams");
        if (select.value == 'Premier League') {
            sel.innerHTML = "";

            @foreach(var team in ViewBag.List[0])   // Premier League
            {
            @: var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
            @: x.setAttribute("value", @team);
            @:var t = document.createTextNode(@team);
            @: x.appendChild(t)
            @: sel.appendChild(x);
                }
        }
        else // the other competitions
```

But i can't use ViewBag in javascript function.

I just want a select that reacts to another select and to put those 2 things in the database.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks!

Comment: I would look to either use an HTML helper to render the box or pull the data from a web service.  Writing the code like would not be the easiest way or the best.  What underlying system are you using MVC5?

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net Core MVC.  I have only a few leagues ( 5), so i can type those manually, but every league has 20+ teams and i took those from database and put them in the ViewBag.List from the controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View, you can build a JavaScript object which holds all leagues and teams, and then read from that object in your JavaScript code:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.List = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
    {
        { "Premier League", new[] { "Arsenal", "Chelsea" } },
        { "Bundesliga",     new[] { "Bayern Munchen", "Wolfsburg" } },
    };

    return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Complete list of leagues and their teams:
    var leagues = {
        @foreach(var l in ViewBag.List)
        {
            @: '@l.Key': [
                    foreach(var team in ViewBag.List[l.Key])
                    {
                        @: '@team',
                    }
            @:  ],
        }
    };
    ...
```

**Example:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/d0FrGr

Comment: Thank you very much, real helpful. It works now. I didn't know why my Viewbag.List is empty in the javascript function.

Comment: Yeah, the `ViewBag` is only available on the server, in the Controller and View while you build the html (or other response), before it is sent back to the client. Here is an overview that may clarify things: [ASP.NET MVC 5 Application lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application/_static/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application1.pdf)